# Reset PHP Array Index

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array that looks like this:

```
[3] => Hello
[7] => Moo
[45] => America
```

What PHP function makes this?

```
[0] => Hello
[1] => Moo
[2] => America
```

Answer (score 307, accepted):

The `array_values()` function <sup>[[docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)]</sup> does that:

```
$a = array(
    3 => "Hello",
    7 => "Moo",
    45 => "America"
);
$b = array_values($a);
print_r($b);
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => Moo
    [2] => America
)
```

Comment: thank you , this is super handy for my case that converted iterator to array from an SPL but I need the result to be indexed from 0

Answer (score 7):

If you want to **reset the key count** of the array for some reason;

```
$array1 = [
  [3]  => 'Hello',
  [7]  => 'Moo',
  [45] => 'America'
];
$array1 = array_merge($array1);
print_r($array1);
```

**Output:**

```
Array(
  [0] => 'Hello',
  [1] => 'Moo',
  [2] => 'America'
)
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use for more efficient way :

```
$a = [
    3 => "Hello",
    7 => "Moo",
    45 => "America"
];

$a = [...$a];
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [array_keys()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function get keys of an array and [array_values()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function to get values of an array.

You want to get values of an array:

```
$array = array( 3 => "Hello", 7 => "Moo", 45 => "America" );

$arrayValues = array_values($array);// returns all values with indexes
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrayValues);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => Moo
    [2] => America
)
```

You want to get keys of an array:

```
$arrayKeys = array_keys($array);// returns all keys with indexes
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arrayKeys);
    echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 45
)
```