# Reset indexes to 1-based array

Tags: php, arrays

I have array with data and key [1, 2, 4, 5].

$array = xxxx;

this is:

```
                       [array] => Array
                            (
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [test] => fdasdfs24
                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [test] => fdasdf23
                                    )

                                [4] => Array
                                    (
                                        [test] => fdasdf4
                                    )

                                [5] => Array
                                    (
                                        [test] => fdasdf34
                                    )

                            )
```

How can i reset indexes in this and array? I would like receive: [1, 2, 3, 4]

```
                       [array] => Array
                            (
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [test] => fdasdfs24
                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [test] => fdasdf23
                                    )

                                [3] => Array
                                    (
                                        [test] => fdasdf4
                                    )

                                [4] => Array
                                    (
                                        [test] => fdasdf34
                                    )

                            )
```

how can i make it? Maybe is for this some function? I dont want doing this mannually - this is only example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reset PHP Array Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536961/reset-php-array-index)

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do here? I believe the goal is to reset the keys, starting with an index of 1.

Comment: @deceze no its not exact duplicate. Its resetting array index to 1 instead of `2`. Thats a big difference.

Comment: Could you post the array in var_export format?  That way other can actually run their test code right off of your array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you index starts as 1 instead of 0, you need to use [`range`](http://php.net/range) function and with the help of [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine) you get the resultant array.

```
array_combine(range(1,4),  array_values($array));
```

To make it more general you can use this,

```
array_combine(range(1,count($array)),  array_values($array));
```

Comment: + for interesting. Albeit **very specific** to the data set.

Answer (score 5):

```
$new_array = array_values($old_array);
```

Comment: Note his index starts at 1.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary thats what my answer fixes!

Answer (score 3):

Just add an element to the beginning, rekey and then shift it off.

```
$array = array_values(array_unshift($array, 'blank'));
unset($array[0]);
```

I didn't test it but that should do it.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($oldArray as $val):
    $newArray[] = $val; //add the value to the new array
endforeach;
```