# Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Hotel\Manager\details.php on line 341

Tags: php

I have an array  in `php` 
Contents of array are

```
print_r($room_array);

Array ( [1] => 102 );
```

Now how do I change the value of index 1 to index 0

Comment: I take it that 'change the value of one index to another index' means that you want to change the key? And how does the error relate to your question? What code did you run to get that error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rebase array keys after unsetting elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943149/rebase-array-keys-after-unsetting-elements)

Comment: Other duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536961/reset-php-array-index

Comment: [Please, do more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) then **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't** working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/im-new-to-stack-overflow-what-are-some-things-i-should-do-and-what-things-wil).

Answer (score 0):

First this is a very unclear question but this is what I think will solve your problem.

```
foreach($room_array as $key=>$value) {
    unset($room_array[$key]);
    $room_array[0] = $value;
}
```

I know this is a very hard coded and not scalable script, but the question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
print_r([...$room_array]);
```

or

```
print_r(array_values($room_array));
```

Regards,